# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields and Content Expiry

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

We are trying to build a mobile app that pulls content from a WordPress page as JSON using a url. The page in WordPress uses Advanced Custom Fields as its underlying structure. None of the Content Expiry plugins I have tried thus far seem to be able to work with custom fields.

We have no Php knowledge, we are just using plugins.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming. **[SOURCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Welcome to SO. This question is off-topic.

Comment: Kindly, but in addition your question is very fuzzy and unclear. Please clarify it, adding more details, including plugin links… But as [**ksno**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6374837/ksno) pointed, this question seems to be off-topic. Try to ask a clear question on Advance Custon Fields plugin support pages instead.